# assembly int10h not blinking

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

why is that the display character is not blinking? i know that the higher bit should be set to 1 in order for the blinking bit to be turn on. ive turn it on and yet nothing happens.

ive research online and sometimes there are issues like this wherein there are times it blinks, other times it doesnt. Thanks

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data
msg db 09,'Steven J',08,'$'
.code
main proc far
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,09h
mov al,'*'
mov bh,00h
mov bl,0f0h
mov cx,12
int 10h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're using a correct video mode using int 0x10, AH=0x00 (as I understand it blinking will only work in a text mode). You can always try specifically enabling the blinking bit too, in case for some reason it has been disabled (using [int 0x10, AX=0x1003](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0117.htm)).

This may also depend on what system you're using - I believe some emulators haven't implemented blinking, and this may be true for some hardware too - although I haven't had enough experience with this function to be able to tell you for sure.

Comment: It depends on how you setup the mode.  You'll need to be in a text mode first off.  You'll then have to have it setup to support blink mode.  Otherwise the "blink bit" is interpreted as a high intensity bit.